# I can't download the mongoose.exe

Tags: windows, file, download, windows-8.1, exe

## The Story

So, I wanted to see what a small web server was like, and I discovered mongoose, a nice, small, simple web server for static sites. Then the horrors arose when I tried downloading it. I tried grabbing it from this site: http://cesanta.com/mongoose.shtml, and found that Chrome always complained about some network error. I then had a friend try downloading it, thinking it was a bad link, but he downloaded it just fine. So I thought, okay whatever, I'll have him transfer it to a flash drive and I can get it off there. I then discovered that I can't get the file off the flash drive. The Windows file copy dialogue would get hung up on 75%, and then suddenly jump to 100% and the file would flicker in the folder, and then disappear. So, I was like okay, maybe I don't need it on my computer, and I'll jut run it off my flash drive, so I ran it, and windows complained saying that the file didn't exist, and suddenly the file on the flash drive disappeared.

## The Questions

Why does this file hate me?

Is there something wrong with my file system?

Is it an issue with the executable itself?

## The Details

My friend and I are both running Windows 8.1
I can download other files just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file can be downloaded from https://mongoose.ws/binary/

Comment: ... Where did that link come from...? But thanks nonetheless. It works! :P

Comment: No longer works :( I can't find an exe anywhere. Just the source.

Comment: The latest edit makes the link work again (since the download is no no longer hidden but lives on the homepage at https://mongoose.ws/)

Comment: mongoose.ws doesn't seem to have the binaries either now nor does the github and the build is failing on github..

Comment: There is a working URL again! \o/

Answer (score 5):

## The Story

Great story, yo. Kudos to your friend for trying to help out.

## The Questions

Obviously this file is possessed and is trying to kill you. Your file system is also out to kill you. Don't blink. Don't even blink.
Blink and you're dead. Don't turn your back, don't look away, and don't blink!

[image: Weeping Angel Security Camera Footage]

## The Details

Now that we've gotten that out of the way, let's try in earnest to find a solution... Luckily, the issue of [a binary not being available](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/discussions/1408#discussioncomment-4956280) has been resolved.<sup>1</sup>

Just go to https://mongoose.ws/binary/ and download the binary for your platform

[image]

- **[Windows](https://github.com/cesanta/binary/releases/download/exe/mongoose.exe)**
  1.Right-click the download button
  2. "Save As" to folder you want to share
  3. Double-click on mongoose.exe
- **[Linux](https://github.com/cesanta/binary/releases/download/exe/mongoose_linux)** / **[MacOS](https://github.com/cesanta/binary/releases/download/exe/mongoose_macos)**

  1. Right-click the download button
  2. "Save As" to `$HOME/mongoose`
  3. Start terminal, `chmod 0755 $HOME/mongoose`
  4. `$HOME/mongoose -d DIRECTORY_TO_SHARE`

<sup>1</sup> as of February 2023

Comment: Looks like things changed again. Updated my answer to reflect recent changes.

Comment: The file also disappeared for me. Reason is that it has been quarantined by Windows defender as a Trojan (Trojan:Win32/Fuery.B!cl)

Comment: Everything has changed as of 2021, the Mongoose home page is completely different, and none of the Cesanta links work, which every other reference tracks back to.

Comment: got it at: https://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/WEB-Servers/Mongoose.shtml and posted on the discussion forum at mongoose.ws requesting at least build instructions

Comment: Ugh. Looks like they changed things _again_. Following any replies to https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/discussions/1408 I'll update my answer here...

Comment: Great story and great solution, I enjoyed every bit of it while trying to not blink or looking   back.